# Matching the string

Tags: javascript

I'm having some difficulty with looping through an array and matching it with a string, I have a search box with an autosuggest, when the user types the suggested string appears.

So the idea is to alert when the matches the variable, here is what I have so far, any help would be great.

```
var DomainCentral = "DomainCentral";
var DomainGuard = "DomainGuard";

    $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      DomainCentral,
      DomainGuard
    ];
    $( "input#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
    for (var i in availableTags){
        if (availableTags == DomainCentral) {
            alert('hello');
        }
    }

  });
```

Comment: `if (availableTags[i] == DomainCentral)`? (Emphasis on the `[i]`) Also, you should not use `for... in` to iterate over arrays.

Comment: Too fast for me, damn.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You should write this as an answer, as it's definitely correct.

Comment: @Reed, that's a simple typographical error, I don't think an answer would benefit much to the community. I opted to vote to close the question instead.

Comment: That makes sense. How did you "vote"? Simply downvoting? or a flag?

Comment: @Reed, it's a vote, but you need 3k rep to do that.

Comment: Thanks for that, it did the trick but now I'm faced with another issue, the alert fires every time rather that when it's entered.

Comment: Edit your question, I'll post an answer to this new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to listen to an event, and do this check when that event happens. This looks like the right event, tho i haven't tried it: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response You'll need to read the input, i.e. `$('input#tags').val()`, and check that value against your array inside the event listener.

Comment: Thanks for that, quite new to event listeners.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm glad I could help. Still this question should be deleted as it's poorly worded and won't be all that helpful to others in the future.